# make unity run in background on android

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I want to make mygame (unity) run in background on android when I click a button.

There is the information that i need to set up plugin and use service so I connected plugin between unity and android and made a button on unity.

When the button is clicked , the `onCreate` method should be activated and the service should be activated.

But i have no idea what to do next. There is no paper to make whole unity game run in background. there is only about the way how to deliver the string like "a, b, c , 1, 2,3" .

according to the docs, i need to use the method called " unitysendmessage()" .but if i use it i can't make methods on unity as service. it just sends strings.

is there any solution to make unity run in background ?

Button on unity

```
 public void andro() {
     _plugins.Call("onCreate");
 }
```

Android code

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         startService(new Intent(this, my.class));
     }
 }

 public class my extends Service {

     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startld) {
         return START_STICKY;
     }

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Explain more plz , do you need to run an android Activity on Unity ?

Comment: @Amin_it  unity can not run in background by itself. so it needs to use android . for example, you can get push alarm or payment if you use android when you make an unity game. so i don't need to run an android activity on unity.

Comment: @Amin_it i mean ... don't need to see activity screen ... just to need to use android 's service...